# Matplotlib legend shows two same colors for a different data

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

I would like to make a function that generate plots for different dataset. My idea is to make list of bank for the function to generate each bank's credit growth or loan to funding ratio. However, whenever I put more than three banks in the list, the plot will show a same colour for two different dataset as seen in the legend(In the latter pic, BNLI has the same color with BBRI for example). Anyone knows how to generate legend which has unique color for each data set?

Here is the code to generate the plot:

```
def plot_by_LFR(bank_list, rotation_of_x_axis_labels = 0):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 6))
    for nama_bank in bank_list:
       x = LFRbank(nama_bank).index
       y = LFRbank(nama_bank)['LFR']
       ax.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', linestyle = '--', label=nama_bank)
       ax.set_xlabel('Periode')
       ax.set_ylabel('LFR')
       ax.set_title('LFR Bank Buku IV Periode 2018-2020')
       ax.legend(loc='upper right')
       fig.tight_layout()
    
       plt.show
```

Here is the picture when I put three banks or less:
[plots generated by function for three or less data, no overlapping color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u7yo.png)

And this is the picture when i put more than three datas on the list:
[plots generated by function for more than three data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cqyd.png)

Comment: Please include your data so that we can reproduce your results.